# Excel VBA, how to achieve this formatting? Nmbr with commas and rounding to 2 decimal

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, rounding

So if we have a number, 99999.23412343  I'm hoping to get it to display 99,999.23  In other words, having a thousands separator comma and 2 decimal places rounded.

I have this code here, which makes values cosmetically look that way, but it doesn't actually round the number.  is there a way to add rounding to this calculation or make the values themselves be 2 decimals?

```
Sub roundcode()

 

    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End Sub
```

Comment: A little unclear: do you want to actually round the numbers (eg turn 42.3456 into 42.35) or just display numbers to 2 decimal places? The Excel function ROUND(x,2) rounds a number to 2dp.

Comment: Do the cells contain **formulas** or **constants** ?

Comment: Use either `WorksheetFunction.Round`, `VBA.Round`, or `ThisWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True`.  Before using the last, read about it's disadvantages.  Before using the first two, read about the differences between the two Rounding functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will apply both actual rounding as well as format rounding:

```
Sub roundd()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Columns("G:G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.HasFormula Then
                txt = "(" & Mid(cell.Formula, 2) & ")"
                cell.Formula = "=ROUND(" & txt & ",2)"
            Else
                cell.Value = .Round(cell.Value, 2)
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
    rng.NumberFormat = "#,000.00"
End Sub
```

It will handle both formulas and constants.

**EDIT#1:**

to avoid the first row, replace:

```
Columns("G:G")
```

with something like:

```
Range("G2:G999999")
```

**EDIT#2:**

Try this instead:

```
Sub roundd()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("G2:G999999"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.HasFormula Then
                txt = "(" & Mid(cell.Formula, 2) & ")"
                cell.Formula = "=ROUND(" & txt & ",2)"
            Else
                If cell.Value <> "" Then
                    cell.Value = .Round(cell.Value, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
    rng.NumberFormat = "#,000.00"
End Sub
```

Comment: This works super well!  One dumb question, if I have a text header in the first row, I noticed it trips an error.  Is it possible to avoid the header row?  I tried changing Set rng = Intersect(Columns("G:G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)  to G2:G but that trips another error..  It looks like the code definitely works, I just need to find a small workaround for the header.

Comment: @Amateurhour35  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Hmm -- still failing and saying type mismatch  -- the line in yellow when running is :  cell.Value = .Round(cell.Value, 2)    --------- I replaced the Set rng = Intersect(Columns("G:G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange) line with Set rng = "G2:G999999"

Comment: @Amateurhour35  See my **EDIT#2:**

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what that format is supposed to do.  If you want thousands with two decimal places simply use:

```
Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "#,000.00"
```

No need to `Select` to format.  For a good reference for all number, time, date formats use the following link https://peltiertech.com/Excel/NumberFormats.html

Comment: The format he is using is the built-in Accounting format.  Of course, like any format, it will only round the display, and not the actual stored value.